# How to overwrite or ignore cloud_RoleInstance with Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, azure-application-insights

We are just starting with Application Insights. Despite that's build mainly for apps running in the cloud, we use it also to track some usage statistics for our WPF client.

For this installation we don't want to track the machine name as it is in **cloud_RoleInstance**. This is a privacy policy problem for us. To store the machine name even gets more critical as in smaller companies, the machine name might be the name of the user. At least in our markets, this is a no go.

This is how the telemetry client is set up for server and WPF client.

```
TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = ApplicationInsightsHelper.InstrumentationKey };

//do not track username...
//telemetryClient.Context.User.Id = Environment.UserName;
telemetryClient.Context.Session.Id = SessionId.ToString();

telemetryClient.Context.Device.OperatingSystem = GetWindowsFriendlyName();

telemetryClient.Context.Component.Version = Version;
telemetryClient.Context.Properties.Add("ComponentName", ComponentName);
telemetryClient.Context.Properties.Add("CustomerId", CustomerId);
```

Now my question is how to setup the telemetry client to remove, obfuscate, overwrite the cloud_RoleInstance property.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, that was easier than I thought:

```
telemetryClient.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = CustomerId;
```

Hope this helps somebody...